# PowerMockito mocking static testing controller in spring 3.2.4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, junit4, springmockito

I am performing some mockito test, but I have some problems with 1 class that have an static method, that I Mocked up in the setUp() method of the test class

Having this class:

```
public class ResponseFileWriteHelper {


    public static void write(HttpServletResponse response, String fileName, StreamWriter writer) {

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "");
        response.setContentType("application/octet");
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(fileName)) {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        }

        try {
            writer.doWrite(response.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }    
    }
}
```

Here the controller I want to test:

```
public class ManageDeviceController extends SimpleFormController {
```

...

```
private void generateDevicexBeneficiaryList(
            Collection<Integer> selectedYears, PriorityAreaKey priorityAreaKey, Language language, Collection<DeviceStatus> statuses, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        final List<ReportItem> reportItems
            = DeviceListReportService.getDevicesxBeneficiaryForYears(selectedYears, priorityAreaKey, language, statuses);

        ResponseFileWriteHelper.write(response, "DevicesxBeneficiaryList.xls", new StreamWriter() {

            @Override
            public void doWrite(OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {
                DeviceListExcelReportRendererBuilder.build().renderToStream(
                    reportItems, outputStream);
            }});
    }
```

}

Here the test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SelectDeviceListExcelReportControllerTest {

    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic (ResponseFileWriteHelper.class);
        EDeviceSessionContext.getInstance().setSession(httpSession);
        when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(httpSession);
        when(request.getLocale()).thenReturn(Locale.ENGLISH);
        messages.initialize();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(ResponseFileWriteHelper.class)
    public void successTest() throws Exception {

        TableItemBuilder tableItemBuilder = 
                new TableItemBuilder(new LabelCellItem("success.test"));

        List<ReportItem> expectedData = Arrays.asList(
            new ReportItem("success.test",Arrays.asList(tableItemBuilder.getTableItem())));

        final ByteArrayOutputStream resultData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ServletOutputStream output = new ServletOutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int val) throws IOException {
                resultData.write(val);
            }
        };

        when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(output);

        when(deviceListReportService.getDevicesxBeneficiaryForYears(
            any(List.class), any(PriorityAreaKey.class), any(Language.class), any(Collection.class))).thenReturn(expectedData);


        doCall();

        //assertArrayEquals(expectedData, resultData);
    }
}
```

But the test crashes because a java.lang.NullPointer here:

```
ResponseFileWriteHelper.write(response, "DevicesxBeneficiaryList.xls", new StreamWriter() {
```

Comment: Did you rememebr to annotate your test class with @PrepareForTest(ResponseFileWriteHelper.class)?

Comment: I've tried now with the same result, I am quite new with mockito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@PrepareForTest()` in only working with `PowerMockRunner.class` in your test class, so you need add the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` in your test class.

But it comes another problem is that you really want using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` as your test runner, thanks powermock already realize this problem, it provider the `PowerMockRunnerDelegate` annotation to achieve it.

The working copy will be like that:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "......"
        )
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*") // to specify that all classes under the specified package be loaded by the system class loader
@PrepareForTest({Static.class})
public void ControllerTest {
    public void testMockStatic() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
        ......
    }
}
```